# How do I get the order_id and order_number on the checkout completed page?

Tags: commerce, 9

I'm trying to get the order information inside the mymodule_preprocess_page hook.

On the normal page I can get it via the $cart. But the $cart is not available on the checkout page anymore. How do I get the order information specifically the order_id and order_number.

This is what I do on other pages:

```
  $order_type = 'physical';
  $cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
  $store = \Drupal::service('commerce_store.current_store')->getStore();
  $cart = $cart_provider->getCart($order_type, $store);
  if ($cart) {
    foreach ($cart->getItems() as $order_item) {
      $orderId = $order_item->get('purchased_entity')[0]->get('target_id')->getValue();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order */
  $order = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('commerce_order');
```